# Экспортировать вложения из класса объектов arcgis с кириллическими символами

Tags: python, gis

Привет.
Нашел скрипт py экспортирующий вложения из ГБД arcgis. [тут](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011912)
С латинскими названиями самих вложений работает, но при попадании на кириллические символы стопорится и вылетает.
Как указать правильную кодировку для работы скрипта с лат и кириллическими символами?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import da
import os

inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID']) as cursor:
   for item in cursor:
      attachment = item[0]
      filenum = "ATT" + str(item[2]) + "_"
      filename = filenum + str(item[1])
      open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
      del item
      del filenum
      del filename
      del attachment
```

Comment: А можно ошибку, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали решение:

`with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID']) as cursor: 
    for item in cursor: 
        attachment = item[0] 
        filenum = u"ATT" + unicode(item[2]) + u"_" 
        filename = filenum + unicode(item[1]) 
        open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())`

Answer (score 0):

Содержание считываемое в курсоре в unicode.

1. Добавьте в начало скрипта `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
2. Сформируйте название файла следующим образом:

   ```
   def f1(x): return x.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1251')  
   filename = f1("ATT{0}_{1}".format(str(item[2]), str(item[1])))
   ```